# Переадресация запросов в Apache

Tags: apache, faq

Подскажите, как такое можно настроить в Apache: Есть сервер с Apache и 2 компьютера. Один компьютер отправляет http запрос на сервер, там проверяется откуда пришло, если с нужного компьютера, то пересылается на третий. Т.е. пересылаются только с одного конкретного на другой, остальные входящие не перенаправляется никуда.

Comment: что именно вы подразумеваете под словами «пересылается на третий»: перенаправление браузера или выполнение прокси-запроса *apache*-ем?

Comment: Без браузера, только переадресация данных, которые пришли

Comment: а я, не дождавшись уточнения, уже ответ про оба варианта подготовил.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

не дождавшись уточнения, что означает слово «пересылается» — то ли запросившему браузеру возвращается перенаправление, то ли *apache* должен сам делать прокси-запрос, я привожу оба ответа.

здесь `1.1.1.1` — адрес, с которого делается запрос, а `site.ru` — куда этот запрос «пересылается».

первый вариант, с перенаправлением браузера:

```
rewriteengine on
rewritecond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^1\.1\.1\.1$
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://site.ru/$1 [L,R=301]
```

второй вариант, с проксированием запроса:

```
rewriteengine on
rewritecond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^1\.1\.1\.1$
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://site.ru/$1 [L,P]
```

---

в обоих вариантах должен быть включен *mod_rewrite*, во втором случае — *mod_proxy* и *mod_proxy_http*.

Comment: А если то куда пересылается не домен,  а имеет только ип?

Comment: тогда напишите *ip*.

Comment: И где прописывать второй вариант, в htaccess?

Comment: Так? ` rewriteengine on
rewritecond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^1\.1\.1\.1$
rewriterule ^(.*)$ ^2\.2\.2\.2$`

Comment: *где прописывать второй вариант?* — там же, где и первый — в конфигурации *virtualhost*-а. если вы разрешили её переопределять с помощью файлов `.htaccess` в *docroot*-е, то можно и в них.

Comment: *Так?* — не понял, что именно вы изменили. я имел ввиду: замените `site.ru` на ip-адрес.

Comment: Просто 2.2.2.2 вместо site.ru без слешей?

Comment: да, просто, без бэк-слэшей.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую.

Comment: `rewriteengine on
rewritecond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^1\.1\.1\.1$
rewriterule ^(.*)$ 2.2.2.2 $1 [L,P]`

Comment: нет. замените строку `site.ru` на строку `2.2.2.2`. буквально.