# SSL Apache с переадресацией

Tags: apache, apache2

Использую такую конфигурацию для переадресации сайта с виртуальной машины с ип 1.1.1.1 через сервер с апачем.

```
rewriteengine on
rewritecond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^1\.1\.1\.1$
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://site.ru/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Установлены *mod_rewrite*, *mod_proxy*, *mod_proxy_http*.

Нужно все тоже самое, но чтоб работало через *https*.

Какие модули добавить и что изменить в конфигурации?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вы привели конфигурацию для [первого из предложенных вариантов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/441691/178576), когда браузеру возвращается [*http*-ответ 301](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_HTTP#301), в соответствии с которым браузер должен сделать переход на предложенный *url*.

в такой ситуации никаких дополнительных модулей в *apache* подключать не нужно, надо всего лишь изменить строку `http` на `https` (в третьей приведённой вами строке).